# the situation of using super via this by access provider operator

Tags: java, this, super

Is it possible to use `this` and `super` together in java in such a way

```
this.super.a;
```

...where `a` is any data member. Trying the above snippet gives an `unexpected token` error.

Is there any other possible way of implementing `this` and `super` using the dot operator?

Comment: What is that construct supposed to do? Why do you think using either `this.a` or `super.a` isn’t sufficient?

Comment: @Anmol Thukral Do you understand the meaning of `this` and `super`?

Comment: @user3437460 yes i know the meaning of this and super both,

Comment: @AnmolThukral Take a look at my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

If `a` is declared as a protected member field, you can just say:

`this.a`

or if you have a getter method defined:

`this.getA();`

Comment: Am I misread or misunderstand the question ? Question is about, using this and super together.

Comment: I'm going more for what he's trying to accomplish, as oppose to how he's trying to accomplish it.  I don't think either answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way and that make much sense to use `this` and `super` together. When you are using `super`, you are already in `this`. There will be no practical reason to do that.

You can just use `super.a`

Answer (score 0):

In a class simply super.a if a is a protected or public member of the parent.

this.a is used when you want to distinguish in a constructor/method the class member a from the parameter a during assignment

Answer (score 0):

## Using [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

First of all, let us look into the usage of `this`.
We don't talk about access modifiers (public / protected / private) first.

```
class Cat
{
    String furColor;

    public Cat(){
        this("white");    //Using "this" to invoke its own constructor
    }
    public Cat(String furColor){
        this.furColor = furColor;    //Using "this" to reference its own class member
    }
}
```

`this` is a reference to the current object. You can use `this` to refer to any member in the current object. If you are not extending your class to other class, you don't really have to worry about the `super` keyword. [All class implicitly extends to class object, but it is not the issue here]

## Using [super](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

Now, let us take a look into `super`.

```
class Animal
{
    String noise;   
}

class Cat extends Animal
{
    String furColor;

    public Cat(){
        this("white");               //Using "this" to invoke its own constructor
    }
    public Cat(String furColor){
        this.furColor = furColor;    //Using "this" to reference its own class member
        noise = "meow!";             //Set the noise for Cat
    }
    public void makeNoise(){
        System.out.println(noise);             //meow!
        System.out.println(this.noise);        //meow!
        System.out.println(super.noise);       //meow!
        System.out.println(this.super.noise);  //Error!
    }
}
```

We can call `super` in the constructor of the subclass to invoke the super class's constructor. (Since you probably already know it, not elaborated here).

1. `System.out.println(noise);` works because `noise` was inherited from Animal class. As long as it is not `private` in the super class, it will be inherited by the subclass.
2. `System.out.println(this.noise);` works because `this.` is used to refer to any member within its own class. Writing `this.noise` is same as writing `noise`.
3. `System.out.println(super.noise);` works because `noise` actually comes from the superclass - `Animal`. Since it is already inherited into Cat class, writing `super.noise` is same as writing `this.noise`.
4. `System.out.println(this.super.noise);` will give you an error during compilation. The syntax is wrong. Logically if you write `this.super`, your intention might trying to refer to your superclass's members. But since all non-private members will be inherited, there is no need to write `this.super.xxx`. Just use `this.xxx` is suffice.

Unless the member is private in the superclass, you can `this.getXXX()` provided that the superclass has an accessor method for that.